# google my maps ~ custom map embed into wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my initial question at stackoverflow. I am developing a wordpress site for a Bed and Breakfast client. On her current site she has a map with legend on the left hand side. I looked into how this was implemented and saw that she was using a site called [mapchannels.com](https://mapchannels.com)

I am creating this custom map with google my maps. I've created an API key and am using that for the map. When I go through the mapchannels protocol, the markers in the legend at left don't look like the markers in the google my maps work space. In addition, when I plug in the iframe code to embed the map, I get an error in the map area that says "Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."

I just want to add a map to this site that not only loads, but has markers that look the same as those in my google maps workspace.

Here is a link to the page that I'm working on https://jpalenhouseblog.com/index.php/map-and-plan-your-stay/
Here is a link to the current website with map embedded via mapchannels.com
I've added links to the following javascripts into the header.php file for my wordpress theme ( Redwood ) and the map still doesn't load.

```
<script src=“https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY" async="" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src=“https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY" async="" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[link to comparison between map embedded on dev site and map in my google maps workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjkXL.jpg)

Any advice on either of these two related questions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The map request you to check your console for technical details. When looking at your error it says `RefererNotAllowedMapError`. Have you added the domain on which you use your map to the whitelist in the developer console?

Comment: Hi Emiel. Thanks for the input. I cannot see anywhere that indicates 'whitelist' in the console. I don't know where to check for tech details either as I'm brand new at creating a map with the my maps environment. Can you tell me where, at least I can add the domain?

Comment: Follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to create your API Key and enable it. And read [this section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) on the same page on how to add your domain in the *application restriction* section in the Google Developer Console.

Comment: Hello again Emiel. I just surfed through the console and my project and had mistakenly added the URL's of the websites that will be hosting to the 'restricted list'. So, of course the map was not loading. My bad. I've removed the URL's from the restricted list and the map is now loading. Thanks for pointing this out, as I would not have investigated this had you not. Much appreciated.

Comment: I guess, when I was adding the URL's I thought that it was restricting the use of the API to ONLY those URL's. I guess I don't understand the nature of API restrictions yet.

Comment: You should be restricting to only the URLs you want to use the API keys. If you had a site in your whitelist but it wasn't working, then you whitelisted it wrong. Make sure you are careful about how you declare the whitelisted URL, use wildcards where you can, etc.

Comment: Hi @ecg8 . I am a little confused by this particular process. When I go to the 'credentials' page for my API key there are two types of restrictions... Application restrictions
An application restriction controls which websites, IP addresses, or applications can use your API key. You can set one application restriction per key.

None
HTTP referrers (web sites)
IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)
Android apps
iOS apps    & API restrictions
API restrictions specify the enabled APIs that this key can call

Don't restrict key
This key can call any API
Restrict key
Select APIs

Comment: addendum to comment for @ecg8 . The API restrictions have a dropdown list of 17 different API types including MAPS API and MAPS JAVASCRIPT API . I'm not sure which if any I should select for this project which is a custom google map.

Comment: Your script tag should look like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#add_key

Comment: If you are trying to show a map on a website and that's all (no geocoding addresses or getting directions or place searching or etc), then you want an application restriction of HTTP referrers and whitelist your actual page, and an API restriction for just maps javascript API

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Comment: Hi @evan . Thanks for doing that. Being pretty new to this, I make some fairly rookie mistakes ha ha. I appreciate the help. Regards, Dennis

Comment: Hi @ecg8 . I'm still not getting it right i guess. i just learned what a 'wildcard' is, a referrer that has asterisks surrounding it. tried that, no luck. i thought that maybe since i am utilizing mapchannels.com for embedding this map, maybe i should put their url in the applications restrictions, that didn't work. FYI I have four API's in this map  Maps JavaScript API 
Places API 
Maps Embed API 
Directions API       Am wondering if that makes a difference? Thanks.

Comment: I can go to your page and see errors in your dev console. The error text is telling you exactly what URL(s) you need to authorize for your map to work.

Comment: @ecg8 is https://console.cloud.google.com/home/ my dev console? i don't see any errors indicated on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the following JS errors in the [dev console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console):

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized:
>   https://www.mapchannels.com/mc6/27915/27915-jph.htm?v=20200217122746
>
> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized:
>   https://jpalenhouseblog.com/index.php/map-and-plan-your-stay/

To fix this I recommend that you first unrestrict your API key; if the map loads with an unrestricted key then you can be certain that the problem is restrictions-related.

Now, to [restrict](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) your API key properly, try adding these domain referrers (with wildcards "*" included, assuming that you own both these domains):

*.mapchannels.com/*
*.jpalenhouseblog.com/*
mapchannels.com/*
jpalenhouseblog.com/*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @evan . Thank you so much for this information. Indeed this was the solution. Thanks also for allowing me to try and figure it out organically with searches and research. That in itself is quite valuable for a novice like me. I was looking at my Google Cloud Platform page(s) and didn't even realize the developers.google.com interface . When I was doing the restrictions, I was including the https:// and would never have thought to begin the URL with a dot . Also, the additional ( closing? ) restrictions with only one asterisk at the end, again would not have known this. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: @drcreative Glad to hear & happy to help! :)